# Calling Unmanaged C++ code from C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have zero experience in C++, but have a few years C# experience.

Are there an examples out there showing how I can create a method in a C++ program which is then called from a C# program using the DLL?

Cheers

Comment: Do you use managed C++ (i.e. Visual C++) ? That changes a lot the way you can interface with both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using p/invoke, you can call C++ code from C#.

Read this: [Calling Win32 DLLs in C# with P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx)

Another small yet good article : [Using P/Invoke to Access Win32 APIs](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/02/18/cominterop.html)

--

EDIT:

This aritcle explains [how to create a DLL library in C and then use it with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/usecdlllibincs.aspx)

Comment: Hi, this solution does not build to a DLL, is there any other way? :(

Answer (score 0):

You can also try compiling the C++ code in Visual Studio to VC++, which is plain old .NET. Avoid the p/invoke, if the code is compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Create some function in C++ with `"extern "C""` to avoid the c++ name mangling and then use PInvoke as suggested by Nawaz is the better way.